# How many pistons are there in honda 70 cc bike?

Tags: honda, motorcycle

How many pistons are there in honda 70 cc bike?according to my understanding,there is only one piston as there is a single spark plug  but i want to confirm my understanding

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only [one piston](https://youtu.be/7W3_9Cg2h_M?si=475lxO56agpnBnBj&t=470) in a Honda 70cc motorcycle engine.

[image]